# Get query string params using Restful / Resourceful / Flatiron

Tags: flatiron.js

I have the following node app using Restful / Resourceful / Flatiron:

app.js

```
var flatiron    = require('flatiron'),
    fixtures    = require('./fixtures'),
    restful     = require('restful'),
    resourceful = require('resourceful');

var app = module.exports = flatiron.app;
app.resources = {};
app.resources.Creature = fixtures.Creature;

app.use(flatiron.plugins.http, {
  headers: {
    'x-powered-by': 'flatiron ' + flatiron.version
  }
});
app.use(restful);
app.start(8000, function(){
  console.log(app.router.routes);
  console.log(' > http server started on port 8000');
  console.log(' > visit: http://localhost:8000/ ');
});
```

Here is the fixtures module:

fixtures.js

```
var fixtures = exports;

var resourceful = require('resourceful');

// // Create a new Creature resource using the Resourceful library //
fixtures.Creature = resourceful.define('creature', function () {

   var self = this;

   this.restful = true;

   this.all = function (callback) {
     console.log(this);
     callback(null, "ok");   };

 });
```

How can I access the request/query string parameters? E.g. if the route is /creatures?foo=bar

I came across [this issue from the Github repo](https://github.com/flatiron/restful/issues/12), but the comments imply there may be a more long winded method of obtaining this data?

I've been looking at the source code for resourceful and I don't see a clear way. Here is the line in question:

https://github.com/flatiron/resourceful/blob/master/lib/resourceful/resource.js#L379

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default versions listed via NPM Package Manager are out of date which caused some confusion.

See the Github issue here:

https://github.com/flatiron/restful/issues/33

Using package.json in combination with NPM install works with the version combinations:

```
"restful": "0.4.4",
"director": "1.1.x",
"resourceful": "0.3.x",
"director-explorer": "*"
```

With this newer version the url format now works in the style of:

/create/find?foo=bar

The method in question is can be found here:

https://github.com/flatiron/restful/blob/master/lib/restful.js#L506

At the time of writing the method looks as follows:

```
  router.get('/' + entity + '/find', function () {
    var res = this.res,
        req = this.req;
    preprocessRequest(req, resource, 'find');
    resource.find(req.restful.data, function(err, result){
      respond(req, res, 200, entity, result);
    });
  });
```

The key component being that req.restful.data is the parsed query string data.